# is there a GAE requests per second limit or number of instances limit now receiving python 10060 error

Tags: python, google-app-engine, resources, limits

sunday 10/06 we were running a GAE Datastore throughput benchmark in python and are receiving this error-"[Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond"

we were generating requests for 6000 users [200 rps, 650 F4_1G instances] everything running fine.
when we added the next 100 users, we began receiving errno 10060 for all users.
we must be exceeding some System[university lab, internet, network devices, network links, GAE, Datastore...] limit. however; no errors are shown on any GAE logs.

thanks tom

Answer (score 1):

From the question I'm understanding that Errno 10060 being generated inside your python test suite.

See this question: [Python: URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 10060]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15820739/python-urlerror-urlopen-error-errno-10060)

You're probably reaching the maximum number of outbound TCP connections on your test machine.