# Python: URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 10060] without using a proxy

Tags: python, proxy, web-crawler, urllib2

**OS: Windows 7; Python 2.7.6 using the Python GUI Shell**

I'm trying to crawl a website using a Python script, and several authors use the urllib and urllib2 libraries. To store the HTML content of the URL in a variable, I've seen a similar approach proposed:

```
import urllib2

c=urllib2.urlopen('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocket_Internet')

contents=c.read( )

print contents
```

urlopen generates an error after a 120+ seconds:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:/Movie_Knowledge_Graph/crawl.py", line 4, in <module>
    c=urllib2.urlopen('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocket_Internet')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 404, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 422, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1214, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1184, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond>
```

I'm aware that we have to set environment variables accordingly, when using a proxy. But, I'm using my home WiFi network which requires **no proxy**. I tried urllib as well, but it generates the same error.

Comment: Possibly duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15820739/python-urlerror-urlopen-error-errno-10060?rq=1

Comment: @iamsudip I've looked into the mentioned question, none of it seems to work for me. I'm not using a proxy to connect to the internet, so I can't figure out what the problem is.