# error: [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed when using solrpy in python

Tags: python-2.7, solr

when i am trying to run the following python code which uses solrpy,

```
enter code here

import solr

s = solr.SolrConnection('http://example.org:8080/solr')
s.add(id=1, title='Lucene in Action', author=['hello','lucky'])
s.commit()
response = s.query('title:lucene')
for hit in response.results:
    print hit['title']
```

i am getting the following error:

error: [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: URLError: <urlopen error \[Errno 10060\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15820739/python-urlerror-urlopen-error-errno-10060)

Answer (score 0):

You should point to a valid Solr (are you sure there is a Solr running at example.org?)