# Urllib2: how to get content of page

Tags: python, urllib2

I have some urls:

```
http://www.avito.ru/ryazan/avtomobili?pmax=50000&f=188_893b13978
http://www.avito.ru/ryazan/avtomobili?pmax=50000&f=188_898b13978
http://www.avito.ru/ryazanskaya_oblast/avtomobili?pmax=50000&f=188_898b13978
http://www.avito.ru/ryazanskaya_oblast/avtomobili?pmax=50000&f=188_898b13978
http://www.avito.ru/ryazanskaya_oblast/avtomobili?pmax=100000&pmin=50000&f=188_898b13978
```

I try to get content of this page I get an error `urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 10060]`
I use code 
`urllib2.urlopen(url).read()`
What I do wrong?

Comment: Try 'ping  http://www.avito.ru/ryazan/avtomobili?pmax=50000&f=188_893b13978" on command prompt and tell us the output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: URLError: <urlopen error \[Errno 10060\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15820739/python-urlerror-urlopen-error-errno-10060)

Comment: @DineshPundkar I can't open it, timeout

Comment: That's why. Issue with internet or network you are working with. Also, please try to open above URLs in browser. It should be open in your browser.

Comment: @DineshPundkar I can't open this in browser too. But yesterday it works well

Comment: Issue with your network. Please check your internet connection first or try to contact Network Administrator. Your code will not work till your internet connection doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine for me. I used `requests` module to get the page. Python `requests` is better. If you dont have `requests` module installed you can install it by `pip install requests`

```
import requests

for url in urls: # if you are using a list to hold your urls
    r = requests.get(url)
    r.content # will display the entire page content
```

If this also doesnt work, its better to check your proxy connection.

Comment: I get to this code `requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='www.avito.ru', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /ryazan/avtomobili?pmax=50000&f=188_893b13978 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x05C6A470>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 10061] \xcf\xee\xe4\xea\xeb\xfe\xf7\xe5\xed\xe8\xe5 \xed\xe5 \xf3\xf1\xf2\xe0\xed\xee\xe2\xeb\xe5\xed\xee,',))
`