# Timeout error while running jupyter

Tags: python, machine-learning, jupyter

I was trying to run jupyter through Ananconda prompt on window 10
and i was getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\asus\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 5, in <module>
    sys.exit(notebook.notebookapp.main())
  File "C:\Users\asus\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\application.py", line 267, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\asus\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 657, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "<decorator-gen-7>", line 2, in initialize
  File "C:\Users\asus\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\asus\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 1296, in initialize
    self.init_webapp()
  File "C:\Users\asus\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 1120, in init_webapp
    self.http_server.listen(port, self.ip)
  File "C:\Users\asus\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tornado\tcpserver.py", line 143, in listen
    self.add_sockets(sockets)
  File "C:\Users\asus\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tornado\tcpserver.py", line 155, in add_sockets
    self.io_loop = IOLoop.current()
  File "C:\Users\asus\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tornado\ioloop.py", line 214, in current
    return IOLoop.instance()
  File "C:\Users\asus\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tornado\ioloop.py", line 162, in instance
    IOLoop._instance = IOLoop()
  File "C:\Users\asus\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tornado\util.py", line 293, in __new__
    instance.initialize(*args, **init_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\asus\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\ioloop.py", line 139, in initialize
    super(ZMQIOLoop, self).initialize(impl=impl, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\asus\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tornado\ioloop.py", line 709, in initialize
    self._waker = Waker()
  File "C:\Users\asus\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tornado\platform\common.py", line 61, in __init__
    self.writer.connect(connect_address)
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

Comment: It may have already been answered. So, please, take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15820739/938261