# Python Urllib.urlopen:IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 10060]

Tags: python, sockets, urllib

```
#!usr/bin/env python
# coding:utf-8

from socket import * 
import urllib2
import urllib
import re

def getHtml(url):
    page = urllib.urlopen(url)
    html = page.read()
    return html

def getImg(html):
    rule = r'src="(.*?\.jpg)" width'
    imgre = re.compile(rule)
    imglist = re.findall(imgre,html)
    i = 0
    for imgurl in imglist:
        i += 1
        urllib.urlretrieve(imgurl,'%d.jpg' %i)

html = getHtml("https://tieba.baidu.com/index.html")

print "downloading....................."
getImg(html)enter code here
```

When I run the code,the *html* and *imglist* could be got,the follow errors are  also showed,now I don't know how to do it.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "C:/Users/18817/Desktop/getjpg.py", line 27, in 
>       getImg(html)
>       File "C:/Users/18817/Desktop/getjpg.py", line 21, in getImg
>       urllib.urlretrieve(imgurl,'E:/getjpg/%s.jpg' %i)
>       File "D:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 98, in urlretrieve
>       return opener.retrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)
>       File "D:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 245, in retrieve
>       fp = self.open(url, data)
>       File "D:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 213, in open
>       return getattr(self, name)(url)
>       File "D:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 457, in open_https
>       return self.http_error(url, fp, errcode, errmsg, headers)
>       File "D:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 377, in http_error
>       result = method(url, fp, errcode, errmsg, headers)
>       File "D:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 642, in http_error_302
>       headers, data)
>       File "D:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 669, in redirect_internal
>       return self.open(newurl)
>       File "D:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 213, in open
>       return getattr(self, name)(url)
>       File "D:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 350, in open_http
>       h.endheaders(data)
>       File "D:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 1038, in endheaders
>       self._send_output(message_body)
>       File "D:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 882, in _send_output
>       self.send(msg)
>       File "D:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 844, in send
>       self.connect()
>       File "D:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 821, in connect
>       self.timeout, self.source_address)
>       File "D:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 575, in create_connection
>       raise err 
>       **IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 10060]**

Comment: Check this stack overflow post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15820739/python-urlerror-urlopen-error-errno-10060

Comment: urllib.urlopen(....) works fine! when execute urllib.urlretrieve(), can't download the picture from the internet

Comment: I installed Python2.7 and Anaconda, are the conflict?@DYZ

Comment: Thank you for your help! I  have found the causes, which are the inaccurately or uncompleted regular expression(re)，so there are wrong url in the list for urllib.urlretrieve().I revised it and got aright results.