# scrape wikipedia by URL within chinese

Tags: python, url, wikipedia, scrape

There

i am trying to scrape tables from wikipedia like

`"https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/北京市"`
or
`"https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8C%97%E4%BA%AC%E5%B8%82"`

my code:

```
word = "北京市"
newword =urllib.parse.quote(word)
URL = "https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + newword
df = urllib.request.urlopen(URL).read()
(or df = pd.read_html(URL))`
```

but it shows me `urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [WinError 10060]`
even when i select url `"https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8C%97%E4%BA%AC%E5%B8%82"` directly

any ideas about this issue
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: URLError: <urlopen error \[Errno 10060\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15820739/python-urlerror-urlopen-error-errno-10060)

Comment: “Across the Great Fire Wall, we can reach every corner in the world“

Comment: @jnylen, Thank you.

Comment: @georgexsh, ......