# Win Error 10060: I cant connect to a server

Tags: python, sockets

I am writing a simple Client-Server connection. When I try it at home, where all devices are on the same network, it is all fine and the code works perfect. But when I try to use it on devices with different networks, this error occures:

> [WinError 10060]  A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

Client Code:

```
host = 'ip_example'
port = 3333
self.s = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM)
print("Connecting")
self.s.connect((host, port))
```

Server Code:

```
host = ''
port = 3333
self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
self.s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
self.s.bind((host, port))
self.s.listen(3)
self.connection, self.addr = self.s.accept()
```

Can someone help me? (BTW, I even tried to disable the firewall)

Comment: Are you sure that whatever you used instead of `ip_example` is an accessible address for the server?  Can you ping it from the client machine, for example?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: URLError: <urlopen error \[Errno 10060\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15820739/python-urlerror-urlopen-error-errno-10060)

Comment: Instead of `ip_example` i am using a ipv6 which i have from cmd when you enter "ipconfig"

Comment: I just tried the suggestion of bosnian coder, but unfortunately it does not work either