# install error for ibm_db with pip (python)

Tags: python, pip, db2

I have tried upgrading pip, installing/upgrading setup tools, a lot of these simple things suggested on here.  Can anyone help?  Thanks,

I've been able to install every other python library without issue.

> Collecting ibm_db==3.0.3
> Using cached ibm_db-3.0.3.tar.gz (794 kB)
> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

```
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

Comment: Which Db2 client did you install?  How?  Does it run?  Did you configure it? EDIT your question , don't use comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The evidence is:

> sock.connect(sa) TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt
> failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a
> period of time, or established connection failed because connected
> host has failed to respond

The python ibm_db module by default will try to download from IBM the tiny footprint `db2cli` driver.  This is what is failing in your case.

This failure can be either a configuration error (on your environment, or your network), or it can be that the IBM website that hosts the db2cli package is temporarily unavailable. More suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15820739/python-urlerror-urlopen-error-errno-10060).  Remember that the `db2cli` driver is independent of python ibm_db, and can be separately installed.

But, if you already have installed a Db2 CLI driver on your workstation, then you can tell python ibm_db to **not** download db2cli during `pip install ibm_db` by setting the `IBM_DB_HOME` environment variable before running the `pip install ibm_db`.  This is documented on the python ibm_db [homepage](https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb) on github, which you should read.  You can download and install a Db2 CLI driver from the IBM website ('Passport Advantage') or you can get a CLI driver from your Db2 DBA at your site. If you already installed a Db2-server on your MS-Windows workstation the it already includes the full Db2 CLI client.

So there are 4 possible CLI drivers from IBM you can use with python ibm_db, (1) the full Db2-client (2) the Db2 runtime client (3) the `db2cli` tiny footprint client, (4) ( for connecting to i-series AS/400 only, the IBM i access odbc package. Any of these can be pre-installed and pre-configured before installing python ibm_db as long as you set the IBM_DB_HOME variable before running `pip install ibm_db`.

Before python ibm_db can connect to a Db2 database, there must exist at least one Db2 CLI driver on your PATH. You can install and configure a Db2 CLI driver **independently** of python ibm_db if you wish to avoid install-time dependencies on the db2cli driver.

Comment: You have not specified the commands you ran, or which Db2-client you installed. EDIT your question to add those details. Don't use comments.