# Specific wifi connection will not allow python to access internet through codes

Tags: python, openssl, wifi, ethernet

I have been running yfinance in python for some time now successfully on multiple older comps (all Dell Windows 10). I have just gotten a new Dell (important?) and with the same exact code from the other systems cannot successfully run yfinance, I receive a WinError 10060 ( sslopen, bad handshakes etc.) BUT when I connect to the internet via ethernet no problems no errors I get all data. Just to annoy myself I connected to my phones wireless internet and the code worked great just as it did with the ethernet. I want to be able to run connections through python over any wifi networks, I know this has to be a settings issue but I don't know what setting(s), any ideas? I appreciate any help in advance!

Comment: any of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15820739/python-urlerror-urlopen-error-errno-10060) solutions help?

Comment: Thanks for the comment Aaron! I did see that page and it does not address the issues I have. I need to dive into the connection with the wifi. The same code works on a different computer for the same wifi so it seems to be exclusive to this comp, probably a new driver. I am trying to compare differences between the configurations of the two comps. Thanks again!