# ConnectionError on poetry add <package>

Tags: python, pip, sendgrid, python-poetry

I'd like to add `SendGrid` package using poetry. I do so using:

```
poetry add sendgrid
```

I then get the following error:

```
 ConnectionError

  HTTPConnectionPool(host='192.168.30.7', port=8080): Max retries exceeded with url: /sendgrid/ (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001FF281963D0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond'))

  at c:\python38\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py:516 in send
      512│             if isinstance(e.reason, _SSLError):
      513│                 # This branch is for urllib3 v1.22 and later.
      514│                 raise SSLError(e, request=request)
      515│
    → 516│             raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
      517│
      518│         except ClosedPoolError as e:
      519│             raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
      520│
```

But if I do `pip install poetry`, it works without any problem.

What could be the issue with the poetry installation?

Comment: Are you able to add any package with poetry? The 10060 error means that poetry is unable to connect to the remote server, which may imply a network or proxy issue on your machine. Check out [the answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16312067/28376), perhaps they can help?

Comment: Yes, seems to an issue due to my VPN connection