# WinError 10060 - urllib3

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, urllib3

Used this code for automated open Chrome:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
html = urlopen("http://www.google.com/").read()
print(html)
```

Getting this error:

```
URLError: <urlopen error [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond>
```

Not sure if it's proxy or timer issue?

Comment: See if this helps - https://stackoverflow.com/a/16312067/7598774