# why does python request response with a timeout error due to connection issue

Tags: python, python-requests, timeout

When trying a very simple https connection request in python i always get a timeout error.
The code is:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://google.com', verify=False)
print(r.content)
```

Doesnt work with verify=True either. Same script runs fine on another computer in the same network.

Error message includes some german messages but it might be helpfull:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\T2000\Scripts\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 200, in _new_conn
    sock = connection.create_connection(
  File "c:\T2000\Scripts\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 85, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "c:\T2000\Scripts\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 73, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] Ein Verbindungsversuch ist fehlgeschlagen, da die Gegenstelle nach einer bestimmten Zeitspanne nicht richtig reagiert hat, oder die hergestellte Verbindung war fehlerhaft, da der verbundene Host nicht reagiert hat
```

I tried a https request and expected a response similar to
powershell command response of Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri https://google.de/
Instead an timeout error occured due to the inability to connect to the API endpoint
Using a sleep function did not work out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: URLError: <urlopen error \[Errno 10060\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15820739/python-urlerror-urlopen-error-errno-10060)