# Couldn't load PUNKT from NLTK

Tags: python, nlp, jupyter, nltk, chatbot

I couldn't load the punkt module from the nltk library in my Jupyter Notebook.

An Error occured when I tried to import 'punkt' as:[image]
"Error loading punkt: <urlopen error [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond>"

Comment: Did you try to apply these steps : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15820739/how-to-resolve-urlerror-urlopen-error-errno-10060.

Comment: Yeah I tried, yet showing the same