# URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 10060] Python

Tags: python

I am getting this error at  `qr_image = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()`. I have gone through all the questions similar to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923703/why-cant-i-get-pythons-urlopen-method-to-work-on-windows) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15820739/python-urlerror-urlopen-error-errno-10060) Answers to these questions suggest that there is a proxy connection problem. However, I am not using any proxies. I may be doing a simple mistake but I am totally stuck here. 
I have cleared the proxy setting that I was using earlier in `internet options>connections>LAN settings`. I have also cleared the `http_proxy` ans `https_proxy` environmental variables.

EDIT: I was previously using a proxy connection but now switched to dialup modem.

```
import urllib2
import urllib
import gspread
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw
from PIL import ImageFont

w = 420

gc = gspread.login('panxxxxxx@gmail.com', 'xxxxxxxx')
wks = gc.open("Spreadsheet").sheet1  # "Spreadsheet" is the name of the Google Spreadsheet made in the account
val = wks.acell('A1').value
print val
# print len(wks.row_values(1))
list_of_lists = wks.get_all_values()
print list_of_lists

url = "https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code?data=BEGIN%3AVCARD%0AVERSION%3A2.1%0AFN%3APraveen+Sridhar%0AN%3A%3BPraveen+Sridhar%0ATEL%3BHOME%3BVOICE%3A9544344104%0AEMAIL%3BHOME%3BINTERNET%3Aprvn431%40gmail.com%0AEND%3AVCARD%0A&amp;size=220x220&amp;margin=0"

for i in range(5):
    idi = list_of_lists[i][0]
    name = list_of_lists[i][1]
    name_url = urllib.quote_plus(list_of_lists[i][1])  # url encoded name for api call
    email = urllib.quote_plus(list_of_lists[i][2])
    number = urllib.quote_plus(list_of_lists[i][3])
    url = "https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=BEGIN%3AVCARD%0AVERSION%3A2.1%0AFN%3A" + name_url + "%0AN%3A%3B" +\
          name_url + "%0ATEL%3BHOME%3BVOICE%3A" + number + "%0AEMAIL%3BHOME%3BINTERNET%3A" +\
          email + "%0AEND%3AVCARD%0A&amp;size=50x50"
    qr_image = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    name_qr = name + ".png"
    outfile = open(name_qr, 'wb')
    outfile.write(qr_image)
    outfile.close()

    qr = Image.open(name_qr)
    qr.thumbnail((120, 120))
    thid = Image.open("tinkerhub_card.png")  # Blank ID Card over which the QR code has to be placed
    thid_new = Image.new('RGB', (420, 680))
    thid_new.paste(thid, (0, 0))
    thid_new.paste(qr, (150, 220))
    id_usr_font = ImageFont.truetype("resources/OpenSans-Regular.ttf", 25)
    id_usr = ImageDraw.Draw(thid_new)
    w1, h1 = id_usr_font.getsize(idi)
    id_usr = id_usr.text(((w - w1) / 2, 150), idi, (0, 0, 0), font=id_usr_font)

    name_usr_font = ImageFont.truetype("resources/OpenSans-Regular.ttf", 30)
    name_usr = ImageDraw.Draw(thid_new)
    name_usr = name_usr.text((90, 365), name, (0, 0, 0), font=name_usr_font)

    thid_new.show()
```

Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/Harshil/Downloads/id-card-tinkerhub.py", line 41, in <module>
        qr_image = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
      File "C:\Anaconda\lib\urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
        return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
      File "C:\Anaconda\lib\urllib2.py", line 431, in open
        response = self._open(req, data)
      File "C:\Anaconda\lib\urllib2.py", line 449, in _open
        '_open', req)
      File "C:\Anaconda\lib\urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
        result = func(*args)
      File "C:\Anaconda\lib\urllib2.py", line 1240, in https_open
        context=self._context)
      File "C:\Anaconda\lib\urllib2.py", line 1197, in do_open
        raise URLError(err)
    urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond>

    Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Please post all of the relevant code. Also, a dialup modem??? Why?

Comment: Code added. My proxy connection was blocking many of my connection requests so just temporarily using dialup

Comment: Please do post the whole traceback of what error you are getting.

Comment: You need to configure your connection parameters properly. This problem has nothing to do with Python but rather with your connection; most likely you still need to configure some proxy settings.

Comment: can you please give me some hints? what settings should I change? I have tried everything I know.