# python connection through proxy server

Tags: python

I am trying to connect to website using python

```
html=urllib.urlopen('https://www.python.org').read()
```

Error

```
IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 10060]
```

A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

Please help me to connect through different ways

Comment: Working fine here. Do you have internet? Check this link if you're using a windows machine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923703/why-cant-i-get-pythons-urlopen-method-to-work-on-windows

Comment: HI Sammera,Thanks for the reply . i too have a internet connection but it is proxy server which iam connected to . so ,please help in this

Comment: Looks like you've missed this out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620263/using-an-http-proxy-python

Comment: what ever i do I finally , stuck with this
   urllib2.ProxyHandler({"http":"proxy_ip_address:port_number";}),